# Sending an email to many Emails in the SQL databse

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, email

I have table tb_register with a column Email_Adress. others are Personna, Org_Name, First_Name, Last_Name, Email_Adress, Country.

I want my system to send an email to registered users email address that are in the database, depending on the admin selection of a drop down menu(first Drop Down: All, choose a Country).

The drop down menu has All(the email should be sent to all email addresses in the database) or if he chooses a country a hidden drop down menu laoding all the countries appears and and email is sent to users registered to this country.

My first Drop down menu is ID is category

My ASP code;

```
<%if (pgError.Text.Length >= 1){ %>
    <div style="width:100%; text-align:left; padding:5px;">
        <b><asp:Label ID="pgError" CssClass="pageErrors" runat="server"></asp:Label></b>
    </div>
    <% } %>
    <div class="sendTo">
        <table class="SendMail">
            <tr>
                <td class="SendTD">Send To:</td>
                <td class="cateGory">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="category" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="category_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
                        <asp:ListItem>Select Category</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>....................................</asp:ListItem>

                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Subcategory" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2" class="AllDrops">
                    <div class="country">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="Countryname" runat="server" Width="200px" Visible="False" >
                        <asp:ListItem>Select a Country</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>-------------------------</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList></div>
  <div class="Regions">            
<asp:DropDownList ID="Regions" runat="server" Width="200px" Visible="False" >
                        <asp:ListItem>Select a Region</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>-------------------------</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList></div>
      <div class="personna">
              <asp:DropDownList ID="Persona" runat="server" Width="150px" Visible="False">
                                 <asp:ListItem>Choose Personna</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>.....................................</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>          </div>    </td>



            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Subject:</td>
                <td class="Subject">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="subject" runat="server" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox><asp:Label ID="subjecterror" CssClass="pageErrors" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="BodyTitle">Body:</td>
                <td class="textArea">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="BoDyEmail" runat="server" Height="200px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="520px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Attachment:</td>
                <td class="FileUpload">
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileAttachment" runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="Send" runat="server" Text="Send Mail" OnClick="Send_Click" />
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

        </table>



    </div>
```

My C# code

```
public partial class BulkSend : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //connection for the datareader
            string csoWConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegisterCon"].ToString();
            SqlConnection csoW_connection = new SqlConnection(csoWConn);
            string database = csoW_connection.DataSource.ToString();


            theSessionUserID.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["thisUserName"]);
            //if the user is still logged in, load the user's known profile data
            if (Session["thisUserID"] != null)
            {

                if (!IsPostBack)
                {

                    try
                    {

                        csoW_connection.Open();
                        String categoryDDL = @"SELECT Category_ID, Category_Name FROM Email_Category ORDER BY Category_ID";
                        SqlCommand categoryTypeCmd = new SqlCommand(categoryDDL, csoW_connection);
                        SqlDataAdapter categorysAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(categoryTypeCmd);
                        DataSet categoryType = new DataSet();
                        categorysAdapter.Fill(categoryType);
                        csoW_connection.Close();


                        //List of Category
                        category.DataSource = categoryType.Tables[0];
                        category.DataValueField = "Category_ID";
                        category.DataTextField = "Category_Name";
                        category.DataBind();

                        csoW_connection.Open();
                        String myCountriesDDL = @"SELECT country_ID, country_Name FROM tb_countries ORDER BY country_Name";
                        SqlCommand ctryCmd = new SqlCommand(myCountriesDDL, csoW_connection);
                        SqlDataAdapter countriesAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(ctryCmd);
                        DataSet mycountries = new DataSet();
                        countriesAdapter.Fill(mycountries);
                        csoW_connection.Close();

                        //List of actor countries
                        Countryname.DataSource = mycountries.Tables[0];
                        Countryname.DataValueField = "country_ID";
                        Countryname.DataTextField = "country_Name";
                        Countryname.DataBind();

                        //UenpRegions type list
                        csoW_connection.Open();
                        String RegionDDL = @"SELECT * FROM tb_WorldRegion ORDER BY Region_ID";
                        SqlCommand RegionCmd = new SqlCommand(RegionDDL, csoW_connection);
                        SqlDataAdapter RegionsAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(RegionCmd);
                        DataSet Regions = new DataSet();
                        RegionsAdapter.Fill(Regions);
                        csoW_connection.Close();


                        //List of Personna
                        Regions.DataSource = Regions.Tables[0];
                        Regions.DataValueField = "Region_ID";
                        Regions.DataTextField = "Region_Name";
                        Regions.DataBind();

                        csoW_connection.Open();
                        String PersonnaTypesDDL = @"SELECT Personna_ID, Personna_Type FROM tb_personna ORDER BY Personna_Type";
                        SqlCommand personnaTypeCmd = new SqlCommand(PersonnaTypesDDL, csoW_connection);
                        SqlDataAdapter organisationsAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(personnaTypeCmd);
                        DataSet personnaType = new DataSet();
                        organisationsAdapter.Fill(personnaType);
                        csoW_connection.Close();


                        //List of Personna
                        Persona.DataSource = personnaType.Tables[0];
                        Persona.DataValueField = "Personna_ID";
                        Persona.DataTextField = "Personna_Type";
                        Persona.DataBind();



                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Response.Write("Error");
                    }




                }

            }

            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
            }


        } 





        protected void category_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           string Check = category.SelectedItem.Text;

          if (Check == "Country")
            {
                Countryname.Visible = true;
                Subcategory.Visible = true;
                Subcategory.Text = "Choose a Country";
                Regions.Visible = false;
                Persona.Visible = false;
            }

         if (Check == "Region") {
                Countryname.Visible = false;
                Regions.Visible = true;
                Subcategory.Visible = true;
                Subcategory.Text = "Choose a Region";
                Persona.Visible = false;
            }


         if (Check == "Personna")
            {
                Persona.Visible = true;
                Subcategory.Visible = true;
                Subcategory.Text = "Choose a Personna";
                Countryname.Visible = false;
                Regions.Visible = false;
            }



        }

        protected void Send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //First name
            if (subject.Text.Trim().Length < 1)
            {
                subjecterror.Text = " &nbsp; Please enter the <b>SUBJECT OF THE EMAIL</b>";
                pgError.Text = subjecterror.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                subject.Text = subject.Text.Replace("'", "&#39;");
            }

            try
            {

            }
            catch { }
        }

    }
}
```

I have tried this but error...and it is a compromise because it is not what I wanted to do but still it is not working

```
try{
            string Bulksubject = subject.Text;
            string body=BoDyEmail.Text;

            foreach (GridViewRow item in LoadEmails.Rows)
            {

                string email = item.Cells[4].Text.Trim();

                MailMessage BulkEmail = new MailMessage();

                BulkEmail.From = new MailAddress("civil.society@me.org");
                BulkEmail.To.Add(new MailAddress(email));
                //BulkEmail.To.Add(email);
                MailAddress copy = new MailAddress("izotieno@me.com");
                BulkEmail.Bcc.Add(copy);

                BulkEmail.Subject = Bulksubject;

                BulkEmail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                string htmlBody;

                htmlBody = "<div style='margin-left:25%;margin-right:25%;margin-top:5%;border-width:1px; border-color:#CCCCCC; border-style:solid;' align='center'>"
                            + body
                            + "</div>";


                BulkEmail.Body = htmlBody;

                if (FileAttachment.HasFile)
                {
                    BulkEmail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(FileAttachment.PostedFile.InputStream, FileAttachment.FileName));
                }


                SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient();

                smtpServer.Send(BulkEmail);

                pgError.Text = "Mail sent successfully";
            }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)

            {


                    Response.Write("Exception Message: " + ex.Message);

                    pgError.Text = "We are expereinecing technical difficulties. Sorry";

                }
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
GridView Code
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //connection for the datareader
            string csoWConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegisterCon"].ToString();
            SqlConnection csoW_connection = new SqlConnection(csoWConn);
            string database = csoW_connection.DataSource.ToString();

            theSessionUserID.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["thisUserName"]);

            //if the user is still logged in, load the user's known profile data
            if (Session["thisUserID"] != null)
            {

                if (!IsPostBack)
                {


                  try
                    {

                      fillgrid();

                    }
                catch
                    {
                        Response.Write("Error Couldn't load data");
                    }
                    finally {
                        csoW_connection.Close();
                    }
}




public void fillgrid(){
                //connection for the datareader
            string csoWConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegisterCon"].ToString();
            SqlConnection csoW_connection = new SqlConnection(csoWConn);
            string database = csoW_connection.DataSource.ToString();


    csoW_connection.Open();
                        DataTable dt;
                        String SQL = @"SELECT Registration_ID, Personna, Org_Name, First_Name, Last_Name, Email_Adress, country_Name FROM vw_ViewAll ORDER BY Registration_ID";

                        {
                            using (SqlCommand ctryCmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, csoW_connection))
                            {
                                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(ctryCmd))
                                {
                                    dt = new DataTable("tbl");
                                    da.Fill(dt);
                                }
                            }
                        }

    LoadEmails.DataSource = dt;

    LoadEmails.DataBind();
    Cache["Data"] = dt;

}
```

//////////////////////////////////ASP GRIDVIEW///////////////////////////////

```
<div class="GridView">
    <asp:GridView ID="LoadEmails" runat="server"  BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3"  HorizontalAlign="Center" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="10" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDeleting="LoadEmails_RowDeleting" OnPageIndexChanging="LoadEmails_PageIndexChanging" OnRowEditing="LoadEmails_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="LoadEmails_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="LoadEmails_RowUpdating" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Personna">
                <EditItemTemplate>

                    <asp:TextBox ID="editPersonna" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Personna") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>


                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Personna") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Organization Name">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="EditOrgName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Org_Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Org_Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="editFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("First_Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("First_Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="EditLastName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Last_Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Last_Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="EditEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Email_Adress") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Email_Adress") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Country">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="editCountry" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("country_Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("country_Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Edition" ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Deletion" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" Visible="False">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="EditID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Registration_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Registration_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />

         <PagerSettings
            Position="Bottom"
            Mode="NumericFirstLast"
             PageButtonCount="20"
            FirstPageText="First"
            LastPageText="Last"
            NextPageText="Next"
            PreviousPageText="Prev"
             />

        <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
    </asp:GridView>

        </div>
```

My Grid has the following field in that order from the top bottom marching Left to right
1.Personna
2.orgnaization name
3.First Name
4.Last Name
5.Email
6.Country
7.Edition
8.Deletion
9.ID-Hidden

so the cell[]. Text should be 4 if am not mistaken but an error I get is

Exception Message: The parameter 'address' cannot be an empty string. Parameter name: address

Please help

Comment: Where is your GridView? How do you populate it?

Comment: Update see above to get the gridview

Comment: Ahh, so Email Address is in a Label control then? You will need to use FindControl() to get the Label control and then you can get the Text value from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not adding the Email address directly to the grid view - you are binding the value to a label control (as below)

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Email_Adress") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

In order to get the value you first need to get a reference to the Label control (via the ID) then you can get the Label Text property which will give you your email address and then you can continue with the rest of the email sending code - like this

```
foreach (GridViewRow item in LoadEmails.Rows) 
{
    Label lblEmail = (Label)item.FindControl("Label5");

    if(lblEmail != null)
    {
        string email = lblEmail.Text;

        //do email sending 
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked like a charm Thank you very much kevin......Thank you...But my attachment is blank, the attachment is there in the email but when you open it, it is blank :/

Answer (score 0):

try put this

foreach (GridViewRow item in LoadEmails.Rows)
            {

```
            string email = item.Cells[4].Text.Trim();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
            {
              //CODE
            }
```

I think the email is blank

try debug to see this because here this code works

Comment: considering that my grid has 1.Personna 2.orgnaization name 3.First Name 4.Last Name 5.Email 6.Country 7.Edition 8.Deletion 9.ID-Hidden..item.Cells[4].  is right? right? becuase Personna  will be 0 column then orgnaization name will be 1 all the way to email which will be 4(column that has email addresses?), is that correct

Comment: @IsaiahOtieno Yes, if you see the grid with "1.Personna 2.orgnaization name 3.First Name 4.Last Name 5.Email 6.Country 7.Edition 8.Deletion 9.ID-Hidden" in background e-mail is column 4

Comment: I have tyried yur solution above but I get this error: string' does not contain a definition for 'isnullorempty'...my frame work is targetFramework="4.0" />

Comment: @IsaiahOtieno sorry, i update the answer, string.IsNullOrEmpty(email)

Comment: Thank you for your help. It does not throw an exception but still does not send an email

Comment: can you just help with the code for sending an email to all emails in the database, i will figure out the rest later

Comment: @IsaiahOtieno your code in string email = item.Cells[4].Text.Trim(); getting email null, you need to debug and find why, in my code its works :/

Comment: try put email in code

string email = "mail@mail.com";